# Save multiple images with different name in folder

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to read image from one folder and save new images in different folder with different names. I need all of them in different names because they are generated with different affine2d values. For example images in a1 folder will be aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4,aa5.... and images in a2 folder will be bb1,bb2,bb3.... is there any way for do that ?

'''

```
srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\*.jpg'); 
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
filename = strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\',srcFiles(i).name);
im = imread(filename);
aform = affine2d([1 0 0; .1 1 0; 0 0 1])
bform = affine2d([1 0 0; .2 1 0; 0 0 1])
cform = affine2d([1 0 0; .3 1 0; 0 0 1])
dform = affine2d([1 0 0; .4 1 0; 0 0 1])
eform = affine2d([1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1])
fform = affine2d([1 0 0; .6 1 0; 0 0 1])
gform = affine2d([1 0 0; .7 1 0; 0 0 1])
hform = affine2d([1 0 0; .8 1 0; 0 0 1])
jform = affine2d([1 0 0; .9 1 0; 0 0 1])
a = imwarp(im,aform);
b = imwarp(im,bform);
c = imwarp(im,cform);
d = imwarp(im,dform);
e = imwarp(im,eform);
f = imwarp(im,fform);
g = imwarp(im,gform);
h = imwarp(im,hform);
j = imwarp(im,jform);
newfilename=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a1\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename1=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a2\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename2=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a3\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename3=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a4\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename4=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a5\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename5=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a6\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename6=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a7\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename7=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a8\',srcFiles(i).name);
newfilename8=strcat('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\a9\',srcFiles(i).name);
imwrite(a,newfilename,'jpg');
imwrite(b,newfilename1,'jpg');
imwrite(c,newfilename2,'jpg');
imwrite(d,newfilename3,'jpg');
imwrite(e,newfilename4,'jpg');
imwrite(f,newfilename5,'jpg');
imwrite(g,newfilename6,'jpg');
imwrite(h,newfilename7,'jpg');
imwrite(j,newfilename8,'jpg');
end
```

'''

Comment: This doesn't look related to Python to me. I may be mistaken but it seems rather wasteful to try and load all your images into memory at the same time if they are independent - surely you would be better off doing one at a time?

Comment: i am sorry this is matlab code, i delete the tag for python

Comment: i am just trying to save some time with doing all of them together, trying to find out how can I save these new created images with different names. Because I have 40 different people and each of them have at least 300 image, in the end when I am putting them in training they will be all in same folder so they can not have same name. Until now I was just creating data and changing names for each file with following python code. But I don't wanna waste time with doing that.

Comment: import os
# Function to rename multiple files
def main():
   i = 0
   path="C:/Users/mstfy/Desktop/Matlab/alex/affine9/"
   for filename in os.listdir(path):
      my_dest ="p" + str(i) + ".jpg"
      my_source =path + filename
      my_dest =path + my_dest
      # rename() function will
      # rename all the files
      os.rename(my_source, my_dest)
      i += 1
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Calling main() function
   main()

Comment: Please don't put code in comments where it is unformatted and hard to read. It's generally better to edit your question and make sure it is up-to-date and correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking for but I felt, that your code could be a bit more automated if you think more in looks and more complex structures (although I just used a 3D matrix now;) )

```
% build a 3D matrix to store all transformation matrices
Mat = cat(3,[1 0 0; .1 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .2 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .3 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .4 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .5 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .6 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .7 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .8 1 0; 0 0 1],...
            [1 0 0; .9 1 0; 0 0 1]);
srcFiles = dir('C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1\*.jpg'); 
for i = 1:length(srcFiles)
    % load file (use fullfile() + the path from the list to make this
    % generic for every platform)
    path2img = fullfile(srcFiles(i).folder,srcFiles(i).name);
    % read image
    img = imread(path2img);
    for j = 1:size(Mat,3)
        % transform image
        form = affine2d(Mat(:,:,j));
        img_trf = imwarp(img,form);

        %% save image
        % folder name
        fldrNm = num2str(j,'a%d');
        path2fldr = fullfile(srcFiles(i).folder,fldrNm);
        % create new folder if it does not exist yet
        if i == 1 && exist(path2fldr,'dir') ~=7
            mkdir(path2fldr)
        end

        path2save = fullfile(path2fldrsrcFiles(i).name);
        % store new image
        imwrite(img_trf,path2save,'jpg');
    end
end
```

In fact, if your transformation matrix follows this pattern, you can even automate its generation:

```
% allocate memory
NumMat = 100;
Mat = NaN(3,3,NumMat);
for i = 1:NumMat
   Mat(:,:,i) = [1 0 0; i/10 1 0; 0 0 1];
end
```

And in case you want to save even the smallest amount of time, you can to the `affine2d` beforehand but this requires to save it to a struct-array or a cell-array, and I don't know if you are already this far ;)

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a perfect place to use a loop.

```
rootdir='C:\Users\mstfy\Desktop\Matlab\alex\Train1\Person1';
srcFiles = dir([rootdir filesep '*.jpg']); 
for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
    filename = [rootdir filesep srcFiles(i).name];
    im = imread(filename);
    for j=1:9
        xform = affine2d([1 0 0; .1*j 1 0; 0 0 1]);
        newim = imwarp(im,xform);
        newfilename= [rootdir filesep sprintf('a%d',j) filesep srcFiles(i).name];
        imwrite(newim,newfilename,'jpg');
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer , I also wanna save these images with different names. For example in a1 folder I wanna save images as aa1.jpg,aa2.jpg.... etc and for a2 folder I wanna save ab1.jpg, ab2.jpg... how can I do that ?

Comment: you can use `sprint('aa%d.jpg',j)` to replace `srcFiles(i).name` in my script when creating the newfilename, i.e. the line should read `newfilename= [rootdir filesep sprintf('a%d',j) filesep sprint('aa%d.jpg',j)];`